# Call to undefined method PHP error with Vector Skin

Tags: mediawiki

I am getting the issue for this line: $m_skin = $wgUser->getSkin();

PHP:

# acquire a skin object:
    $m_skin = $wgUser->getSkin();

```
# build the breadcrumbs trail:
$m_trail = "<div id=\"BreadCrumbsTrail\">&nbsp;<i>Bread crumbs:</i> ";
for( $i = 0; $i <= $m_count; $i++ ) {
  $m_trail .= $m_skin->makeLink( $m_BreadCrumbs[$i] );
  if( $i < $m_count ) $m_trail .= $wgBreadCrumbsDelimiter;
}
$m_trail .= '&nbsp;</div>';
$wgOut->addHTML( $m_trail );
```

error is:
[4980dec6] /mediawiki/index.php/Hardware Exception from line 1619 of C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Skin.php: Call to undefined method SkinVector::makeLink

Backtrace:

```
0 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\extensions\Breadcrumbs\BreadCrumbs.php(112): Skin->__call(string, array)
1 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\extensions\Breadcrumbs\BreadCrumbs.php(112): SkinVector->makeLink(string)
2 [internal function]: BreadCrumbs->show(Article, boolean, boolean)
3 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Hooks.php(199): call_user_func_array(array, array)
4 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\GlobalFunctions.php(3877): Hooks::run(string, array)
5 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Article.php(615): wfRunHooks(string, array)
6 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\actions\ViewAction.php(44): Article->view()
7 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Wiki.php(448): ViewAction->show()
8 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Wiki.php(312): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
9 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Wiki.php(602): MediaWiki->performRequest()
10 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\includes\Wiki.php(467): MediaWiki->main()
11 C:\wamp\www\mediawiki\index.php(49): MediaWiki->run()
12 {main}
```

Please help, I cannot find any sources to help me resolve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What MediaWiki version are you using? This seems to be an issue with an [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aBreadCrumbs_%28Kimon%29), that is not compatible with newer MediaWiki versions (it was last updated in 2007!). Try disabling the extension “BreadCrumbs”, and see if things start working for you!

You might get away with replacing `$m_skin->makeLink` with `$m_skin->userLink`, depending on your versions, and what else might be broken.

Comment: I am using mediawiki 1.22.1. I did see it was last updated a while ago. I was hoping someone would be able to update with a few quick fixes to get it working though, since I am not able to find any other extension that can do the job I am looking for.

This is the extension with its code, any help would be appreciated (and changing to userlink did not work as it errors on the line before it:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BreadCrumbs_%28Kimon%29